# Serial ports, Windows, and Flask

Tags: python, windows, flask, pyserial

Background:  I am working on a Flask application.  Part of the functionality of this app involves reading data from an RFID device connected via USB.  Communication from the port is handled in this class:

```
import serial, serial.tools.list_ports

class CardReader:

    def __init__(self, device_name=None):
      self.port = self.set_port(device_name)
      self.baudrate = 9600
      self.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
      self.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
      self.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
      self.timeout = 1
      self.ser = serial.Serial(
          port=self.port,
          baudrate=self.baudrate,
          bytesize=self.bytesize,
          parity=self.parity,
          stopbits=self.stopbits,
          timeout=self.timeout
      )

    def set_port(self, device_name=None):
      if not device_name:
          device_name = 'USB to UART Bridge'
      ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
      for port in ports:
          print("Name: " + port.name + "  " + "Desc: " + port.description + "Device: " + port.device)
          if device_name in port.name or device_name in port.description:
              return port.device
      raise Exception("No port found with the device name: " + port.device)

    def get_data(self):
      card_number = None
      facility_code = None
      try:
        if self.ser.in_waiting > 0:
          data = self.ser.readline().decode()
          clean = data[4:]
          if clean:
            clean_int = int(clean, 16)
            card_number = (clean_int >> 1) & 0x7FFFF # Bitshift to remove parity and mask to isolate 19 bits
            facility_code = (clean_int >> 20)
            print(card_number)
          while self.ser.in_waiting:
              self.ser.readline()
          self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
          return (card_number, facility_code)
        else:
            return None
      except Exception as e:
         print(f"An error occurred while reading badge data: {e}")
         return None

    def get_ports(self):
      try:
        ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        port_list = []
        for port in ports:
          print(port)
          port_list.append(port.device)
        print(port_list)
        return port_list
      except Exception as e:
         print(f"An error occurred while getting available serial ports: {e}")
         return []
       
    def close(self):
      self.ser.close()
```

When the app runs in a Linux environment, previous class works as expected. When I run the app in a Windows environment, the `set_port` method returns the exception and I get this error:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

I verified that the drivers for the device were installed and that the port was indeed COM3. Then I checked Process Explorer and found that the process using the COM3 port is the Flask app. So something about the app is preventing the CardReader from accessing the port, I think?  I just can't find anything about how to fix this (Most of the Python/serial port info I find is specific to Arduino).  I've added what I *think* is the relevant code from the `__init__.py` and `views.py` files here:
`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from card_reader.reader import CardReader
from flask_seeder import FlaskSeeder
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "dev"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///project.db"


try:
  os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
except OSError:
  pass

db = SQLAlchemy()

card_reader = CardReader() # Note- add option for timeout prefs?
migrate = Migrate()
seeder = FlaskSeeder()

db.init_app(app)
migrate.init_app(app, db)
seeder.init_app(app, db)

from .admin import bp as admin_bp

app.register_blueprint(admin_bp)

from .views import bp as views_bp

app.register_blueprint(views_bp)
```

File `views.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, escape, Blueprint, session, jsonify, make_response
from database.class_models import *
from database.user_options import add_new_user, remove_user
from .admin import login_required
from . import db, card_reader
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

# A bunch of other routes excluded for brevity

# Route for the card reader test page
@bp.route("/card_test/", methods=['GET'])
def card_test():
  return render_template('card_test.html')
# Route for checking the queue where card data gets read to
# Using flask.make_response and flask.jsonify to create an http response header.
# https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.make_response.html
# https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.jsonify.html
# https://api.jquery.com/ (Used in card_test.html to update page)

@bp.route("/card_data/")
def card_data():
    card_data = card_reader.get_data()
    if card_data is not None:
        card_number, facility_code = card_data
    else:
        card_number, facility_code = None, None

    return jsonify(card_number=card_number, facility_code=facility_code)
```